How to map scores from one table to another when the cell contains operators
I performed OLS regression on a dataset and I have the predicted Diagnostic_Score but the mapping table (norms) can have two operators - e.g. >= and <=. Is there a way to map the predicted score to the percentile?
My first thought was to map the scores that I can match and the ones that do not match I know must to be associated with a percentile that has an operator in the Diagnostic_Score column. I could then use numpy.select and create the conditions and choices. Does that approach make sense or is there an easier way to map the test percentile to the predicted score without having to manually create a 108 conditions and 108 choices for numpy.select?
Here is a sample
import pandas as pd

d = {'percentile': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 2}, 'Subject': {0: 'Math', 1: 'Math', 2: 'Math', 3: 'Math', 4: 'Math', 5: 'Math', 6: 'Math', 7: 'Math', 8: 'Math', 9: 'Math', 10: 'Math', 11: 'Math', 12: 'Math', 13: 'Math', 14: 'Math', 15: 'Math', 16: 'Math', 17: 'Math'}, 'Term': {0: 'Fall', 1: 'Fall', 2: 'Fall', 3: 'Fall', 4: 'Fall', 5: 'Fall', 6: 'Fall', 7: 'Fall', 8: 'Fall', 9: 'Fall', 10: 'Fall', 11: 'Fall', 12: 'Fall', 13: 'Fall', 14: 'Fall', 15: 'Fall', 16: 'Fall', 17: 'Fall'}, 'Grade_Level': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 5, 15: 6, 16: 7, 17: 8}, 'Diagnostic_Score': {0: '<=296', 1: '<=322', 2: '<=352', 3: '<=372', 4: '<=390', 5: '<=405', 6: '<=412', 7: '<=423', 8: '<=434', 9: '297', 10: '323', 11: '353', 12: '373', 13: '391', 14: '406', 15: '413', 16: '424', 17: '435'}}

norms = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Term': ['Fall', 'Fall', 'Fall', 'Fall'],
               'Subject': ['Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math'],
               'Grade_Level': [0, 3, 5, 7],
               'Predicted Score': [290, 300, 406, 424]})

My expected output is
   Term Subject  Grade_Level  Predicted Score  Percentile
0  Fall    Math            0              290           1
1  Fall    Math            3              300           1
2  Fall    Math            5              406           2
3  Fall    Math            7              424           2

norms table
    percentile Subject  Term  Grade_Level Diagnostic_Score
0            1    Math  Fall            0            <=296
1            1    Math  Fall            1            <=322
2            1    Math  Fall            2            <=352
3            1    Math  Fall            3            <=372
4            1    Math  Fall            4            <=390
5            1    Math  Fall            5            <=405
6            1    Math  Fall            6            <=412
7            1    Math  Fall            7            <=423
8            1    Math  Fall            8            <=434
9            2    Math  Fall            0              297
10           2    Math  Fall            1              323
11           2    Math  Fall            2              353
12           2    Math  Fall            3              373
13           2    Math  Fall            4              391
14           2    Math  Fall            5              406
15           2    Math  Fall            6              413
16           2    Math  Fall            7              424
17           2    Math  Fall            8              435
...         
            99    Math  Spring          8            >=585


You can extract the prefix and perform a merge and a merge_asof:
# add group/score
norms[['group', 'Predicted Score']] = (
    norms['Diagnostic_Score']
    .astype(str)
    .str.extract(r'([<>]=|)(\d+)')
    .astype({1: 'int'})
)
# ensure scores are sorted (for the merge_asof)
norms.sort_values(by='Predicted Score', inplace=True)

# define groups
low   = norms['group'].eq('<=')
high  = norms['group'].eq('>=')
exact = ~(low|high)

# merge
s_ex = df.merge(norms[exact], on=['Subject', 'Term', 'Predicted Score'], how='left')['percentile']
s_lo = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values(by='Predicted Score'),
                     norms[low], by=['Subject', 'Term'], on=['Predicted Score'],
                     direction='forward',
                     ).set_index('index')['percentile']
s_hi = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values(by='Predicted Score'),
                     norms[high], by=['Subject', 'Term'], on=['Predicted Score'],
                     direction='backward'
                     ).set_index('index')['percentile']

# combine
df['Percentile'] = s_ex.fillna(s_lo).fillna(s_hi).astype(norms['percentile'].dtype)

You can actually simplify to two merge_asof:
low   = norms['group'].ne('>=')
s_lo = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values(by='Predicted Score'),
                     norms[low], by=['Subject', 'Term'], on=['Predicted Score'],
                     direction='forward',
                     ).set_index('index')['percentile']
s_hi = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values(by='Predicted Score'),
                     norms[high], by=['Subject', 'Term'], on=['Predicted Score'],
                     direction='backward'
                     ).set_index('index')['percentile']

df['Percentile'] = s_lo.fillna(s_hi).astype(norms['percentile'].dtype)

Output:
   Term Subject  Grade_Level  Predicted Score  Percentile
0  Fall    Math            0              290           1
1  Fall    Math            3              300           1
2  Fall    Math            5              406           2
3  Fall    Math            7              424           2


Works great and is efficient. The other solution is a little slow -- I have 29,000 predicted values I am trying to map.

You could try something like this assuming you have only simple expressions in your norms, e.g. >=, <, <= etc:
Step 1: complete the expressions in norms
is_expr = ~norms.Diagnostic_Score.str.match('^\d+(\.\d+)?$')
norms_expr = norms.assign(Diagnostic_Score=norms.Diagnostic_Score.where(is_expr, '==' + norms.Diagnostic_Score))

norms_expr
#    percentile Subject  Term  Grade_Level Diagnostic_Score
#0            1    Math  Fall            0            <=296
#1            1    Math  Fall            1            <=322
#2            1    Math  Fall            2            <=352
#3            1    Math  Fall            3            <=372
#4            1    Math  Fall            4            <=390
#5            1    Math  Fall            5            <=405
#6            1    Math  Fall            6            <=412
#7            1    Math  Fall            7            <=423
#8            1    Math  Fall            8            <=434
#9            2    Math  Fall            0            ==297
#10           2    Math  Fall            1            ==323
#11           2    Math  Fall            2            ==353
#12           2    Math  Fall            3            ==373
#13           2    Math  Fall            4            ==391
#14           2    Math  Fall            5            ==406
#15           2    Math  Fall            6            ==413
#16           2    Math  Fall            7            ==424
#17           2    Math  Fall            8            ==435

Step 2: merge data and norms_expr;
Step 3: create valid expressions from scores, eval the expression and filter based on the result:
df.merge(norms_expr, how='left')[lambda merged: (merged['Predicted Score'].astype(str) + merged['Diagnostic_Score']).map(eval)]
#   Term Subject  Grade_Level  Predicted Score  percentile Diagnostic_Score
#0  Fall    Math            0              290           1            <=296
#2  Fall    Math            3              300           1            <=372
#5  Fall    Math            5              406           2            ==406
#7  Fall    Math            7              424           2            ==424

Edit: a safer alternative is to use pd.eval instead of eval as the former restricts to python expressions, and hence safer to use.

Nice one, but you might want to use pd.eval in place of eval :)

Hmm yeah pd.eval would be a safer choice. Was looking between literal_eval and eval and didn't realize pd.eval  does something different and in between.
